# Listview can't render bitmap in Imageview using ViewHolder Pattern

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

Its very weird, but true. I am using ViewHolder pattern to increase the list performance. getView() method has bitmap, but the below code can't render the bitmap in the imageview of listview item.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_contact_item, null);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.
}
```

The above can't render bitmap in list row imageview. But the below code does

```
//if(convertView == null) {
    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view_contact_item, null);
    viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
//} else {
//    viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.
//}
```

In this case, everything(search, bitmap assignment to imageview) works fine. But this leads to reduction in list performance, as the layout inflation is happening  every-time.

Kindly help.

Note: I am downloading the bitmaps in sepatrate AsyncTask, and assigning them in the arraylist, which is initially passed to the Adapter.

Comment: `Its very weird, but true. I am using ViewHolder pattern to increase the list performance.` It's not **weird**. It's a **best practice**.

Comment: `can't render the bitmap in the listview.` and `reduction in list performance`.  Sorry but what do you mean? Need any help? With what?

Comment: There is an issue with my custom imageview, hence could not render the bitmap. Sorry folks...:(